# Sticky header with cart button

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, frontend, sticky-menu

I tried to made the header to sticky and put the cart button to the header when the page slide down. I already done with the sticky header, but i can't add the cart button to the sticky header. How can i add the cart button to the sticky header?

**Header not slided down yet :**
[image: Header]

**Sticky header slide down :**
[image]

**Css :**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sections.sticky {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #e4e4e4;
    }

    nav ul li ul.level0.submenu.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all{
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        height: 400px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

**Js :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ "jquery" ], function($){
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.sections').offset().top && !($('.sections').hasClass('sticky'))){
            $('.sections').addClass('sticky');
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
            $('.sections').removeClass('sticky');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think that you would clone with jquery cart element in your `.sections` block. Is a good solution for it I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move "nav-sections" to Header section with XML. then you have to add sticky class to header section, `<header class="page-header sticky">` then you can set sticky cart and menu both with css.

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper"  after="-" />
```